# How to change css width 50% to 100% using Vue

Tags: css, vue.js

How can I change css width from 50% to 100 % when click the button see more detail here >>> [Sample sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-haslett-lx7hz0?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)
[image]

```
<template>
    <div id="theSpecial">Hello World Special</div>
    <button @click="changeWidth">Change width</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      testBoolean: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeWidth() {
      this.testBoolean = true;
      //change width to 100%
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#theSpecial {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make some change on your code
First of all add this to your css

```
.theSpecial{width:50%}
.fullWidth{width:100%}
```

To toggle the full width modify the method

```
changeWidth() {
   this.testBoolean = !this.testBoolean;
   //this will toggle the width on every click
},
```

and then use this in your component template

```
<div class="theSpecial" v-bind:class="{fullWidth:testBoolean}">
```

N.B. change the id into class, beacuse id has more css specifity.
This will toggle the class full width accordly to the value of testBoolean.

This is your [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-joliot-8zncmw?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

Here you can find [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes) about class binding

Comment: Ok, I know what you mean thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```js
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <div id="theSpecial" :class="{ 'full-width': testBoolean }">
      Hello World Special
    </div>
    <button @click="changeWidth">Change width</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      testBoolean: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeWidth() {
      this.testBoolean = true;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```css
#theSpecial {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
}

#theSpecial.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  data() {
    return {
      testBoolean: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeWidth() {
      this.testBoolean = !this.testBoolean;
      //change width to 100%
    },
  },
```

```css
.theSpecial {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
}
.fullwidth {
 background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div :class="(this.testBoolean === true)? 'fullwidth':'theSpecial'">Hello World Special</div>
    <button @click="changeWidth">Change width</button>
```